# Using OpenCV Installed with apt-get From Inside a Conda Environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, conda, opencv

If we are running Python 3.8 scripts inside a conda environment named `foo` and want to use the OpenCV that was installed using `sudo apt install libopencv-dev python3-opencv`, what should we do?

It appears that if we are running Python scripts inside a conda environment, it is unable to find `cv2`. However, if we were to install OpenCV directly into the conda environment, such as

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

then this OpenCV version will be used instead of the one installaed using `apt-get`.

Using Python 3.8 on a Ubuntu 20.04 system. Thanks!